# MySQL Order by number of matches in sibling table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of items and a table of tags that can be attached to those items. In a much more rudimentary way, it's like StackOverflow questions and tags, think of items as questions and tags and StackOverflow tags.

Each item can be tagged with infinite tags, but I want to return results in order of the number of tags matched.

I'll give you my table structure then an example.

Table `tags`

```
id | tag_name
 1   delicious
 2   spicy
 3   sweet
```

Table `item_tags`

```
id | item_id | tag_id | created
 1   1         1        TIMESTAMP
 2   1         2        TIMESTAMP
 3   2         1        TIMESTAMP
 4   2         2        TIMESTAMP
 5   2         3        TIMESTAMP
```

So as you can see, if I searched for the tags "Sweet, Spicy, Delicious" then Item 2 would match all three tags while Item 1 would only match the last two. I would obviously want to return Item 2 first based on its higher number of matched tags.

So if I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM item_tags WHERE tag_id IN(1,2,3) GROUP BY item_id ORDER BY NumberOfMatches
```

Where `NumberOfMatches` is the number of tags matched in the `item_tags` table.

Was hoping to do this without a UNION or anything major, but open to all suggestions.

Comment: Why not count your `item_id` and sort by your return?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(tag_id) AS NumberOfMatches, item_tags.* FROM item_tags WHERE tag_id IN(1,2,3) GROUP BY item_id ORDER BY NumberOfMatches DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are all most there, and try this:

```
select
    it.item_id
from item_tags it
join tags t on it.tag_id = t.id
where t.id in (1, 2, 3)
group by it.item_id
order by count(distinct t.id) desc
```

[**SQLFiddle demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d1b189/3)

If you want to fetch the record by `tag_name`, you must use a `join` like:

```
select
    it.item_id
from item_tags it
join tags t on it.tag_id = t.id
where t.tag_name in ('sweet', 'pic', 'delicious')
group by it.item_id
order by count(distinct t.id) desc
```

or if you have known the exact tag ids, **@Daerik**'s approach will be more efficient. And about performance, here two solutions may have no too big difference.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Could you address the solution in Daerik's comment and discuss any potential performance differences in these two approaches? I'm fairly novice at MySQL, sorry.

Comment: @DanL Updated the answer, please check it.